Interupting CAN communication with STM32
I am working on CAN communication with STM32F429I-Disc1 with TJA1050 transceiver. Standard communication works more than fine. What I would like to do next is to interrupt communication while CAN message with certain ID is present on bus. In other words I would like to detect while new message is started to be send, and after ID field I would like to send e.g. 20 0s (dominant bits) on the bus. HAL_CAN_RxFifo0MsgPendingCallback and HAL_CAN_GetRxMessage give access to complete frames. I need deeper and faster solution. Here are my questions:

Is there a way to solve my task with existing HAL libraries?

Where callback from HAL_CAN_RxFifo0MsgPendingCallback CAN interupt is done? Is it after complete message is received (and validated by crc check) or just after SOF bit received on the bus?


Thank you in advance for your help.
I assume that it can be done using STM32 registers. I tried to get any supplementation of CAN using registers, but without luck to find one. Unfortunately I am not familiar with programming using registers to write my own solution.

No CAN peripheral implementation can do this. You need to write a bitbang version

Easiest way to implement it would be to use a timer output pin on the MCU and tie it to the CAN Tx line with a pull-down. Then activate the pull-down for a given time period. This will cause the message transmission to fail and get resent - then fail again until the bus is dead and your node is bus-off - congrats. This very much sounds like the wrong solution to the wrong problem though. What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

My problem is to implement attacks on CAN node/bus. first kind of attack would be bus off attack by interrupting of the message transmit.
This would be pretty simple with your idea (on every message, without verification of msg ID), basically like this: 1) detect SOF on Can Rx 2) wait certain amount of time to pass over header 3) send at leat 6 dominant bits on CanTx
Your solution would probably work, but how to catch certain CAN ID at first?
Another kinds of attack require detecting certain IDs and modifications of those messages.
